# Performance and Browser Crash with Large Group of Lines in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I'm experiencing a performance issue with Fabric.js when displaying a large number of lines in a group. My application allows real-time line drawing, and at the end of the process, the line group can contain up to 50,000 lines. However, when I try to display this line group on the canvas, the browser becomes extremely slow and eventually crashes.

I have tried various approaches to optimize performance, such as using objectCaching to improve rendering, removing unnecessary objects, and adjusting the canvas update frequency. Unfortunately, none of these solutions have solved the problem.

I'm wondering if there are any specific techniques or strategies I could use to effectively handle a large number of lines in Fabric.js. Is it possible to compress or simplify the line data to improve performance? Are there any tips for optimizing rendering or handling line groups in Fabric.js?

I'm open to any suggestions or advice to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!